# Question marks instead of reference, and double question marks instead of figure and table cross-references

Tags: cross-referencing

I wrote my thesis with Sweave (R+LaTeX).
Everything went fine until I bought a new computer. I copied the Sweave file (.Rnw) with all figures and tables, as well as with the bibliography (.bib).

When I compile the file on my new computer, everything is fine, text, figures, tables and layout.... BUT:

- every in-text reference is a question mark, although the bibliography at the end of the document is 100% (number, title etc).
- every cross-reference for the figures and tables is a double question mark, although the figures and tables are 100% (number, title etc).

Any idea of what is wrong?

Thanks,
Elsa

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english=usenglishmax]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand*{\thesubfigure}{(\alphalph{\value{subfigure}})}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=justified,format=plain]{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2cm}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\bfseries}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
%
%
% 
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliography{TemporalPartitioning2}

\end{document}
```

Additional information:

The error I get when running `bibtex` is:

```
> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit) The top-level
> auxiliary file: Draft_PhDThesis_dec2017.aux The style file: acm.bst I
> found no \bibdata command---while reading file
> Draft_PhDThesis_dec2017.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry
> for "Wulf" Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Haeckel"
> Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "bioce" Warning--I didn't
> find a database entry for "Strauss" ... (There was 1 error message)
```

When I look at the .aux file I notice that there is no \bibdata{...} which I believe is created by \bibliography{...}. Not sure what is wrong.

I don't think the problem only lies with the bibtex and the bibliography because the cross-referencing of figures and tables is also not working properly. Unless there are two independent problems, but I don't think so.

The problem definitely lies with the installation because it works fine when I run it on my old laptop... I have not managed to find out what was wrong... if someone can someday shed some light, thanks!

Comment: Did you compiled with `bibtex`? Also, have you tried to compile twice after `bibtex` with `pdflatex`?

Comment: I assume I am compiling with bibtex. All the reference information is in a .bib file (TemporalPartitioning2.bib), which is called with \bibliography{TemporalPartitioning2}. I compiled the document multiple times. However, I don't know if that has anything to do with my issue, but I get the error message that sweave.sty is not found...

Comment: Hi @ElsaBussiere, please check this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153193/120578

Comment: Thanks, I resolved this problem following the instructions on the link you gave me. However, the question marks are still there...

Comment: Please compile by using `pdflatex mainFile` then `bibtex mainFile` and again twice `pdflatex mainFile`... where "mainFile" is the name of your main file without extensions

Comment: This is what I get when running bibtex: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: Draft_PhDThesis_dec2017.aux
The style file: acm.bst
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Draft_PhDThesis_dec2017.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Wulf"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Haeckel"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "bioce"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Strauss"
...
(There was 1 error message)

Comment: perhaps somethingh is wrong with your installation since acm.bst file should be there... If you use debian based linux try: `sudo apt install texlive-bibtex-extra`... in other case I hope someone will see the activity on this question and answer to you...

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved the problem.
In R studio, I clicked: Tools > Global Options > Sweave > Latex editing and compilation

And there, the box 'clean auxiliary output after compile' was ticked.
I unticked it and it now works fine.

Thanks, Elsa

[image: This is a screenshot of the window in which I could change the auxiliary output settings]