# texlive error: File `Sweave.sty' not found. \begin

Tags: texlive, texstudio, sweave

I work with texlive and R, but when I compile the .tex file I received this error

```
File `Sweave.sty' not found. \begin
```

and I found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153193/latex-error-sweave-sty-not-found) but its for miktex users and I have texlive

Comment: It does not matter. For some reason the R people does not put their packages onto CTAN. Find `Sweave.sty` from your R installation and copy it to the same folder as your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution for me is that I put this code in R

```
library("tinytex")
r_texmf(action = "add")
```

and then I compile my .tex document and it works